# How to detect from console or GUI app was run?

Tags: user-interface, console, d, detection

Is it's possible to detect inside app from where it was run? From cmd/bash or from GUI? Assume that we are working in graphical mode, not in pure console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, but sort of. Short answer: better not to try, get the user to tell you via an argument, which you can pre-fill in a shortcut.

Long answer:

In both cases, the program is launched in a similar way: the shell application (whether cmd/bash or Windows explorer/whatever gui launcher linux has) call CreateProcess or ShellExecute on Windows or fork+exec on Linux and the way the user executed it gets lost.

However, the process does have a parent ID which might be useful.... but it isn't reliable either for a few reasons: telling if it is a gui or command line shell isn't easy (best you can do is look at the image name) and the parent might terminate as soon as you launch, so there'd be no parent! (Linux gui apps often fork themselves to detach from the terminal. Of course, if you do this you'd probably know, but if you use a library it might happen without you realizing it.)

Well, the fact that I'm going off on parenthetical asides after every sentence shows how unreliable and complicate that is. If you want to try though, looking at your parent process ID before doing any fork/detaching might be helpful.

BTW looking for a parent console isn't very helpful: a Windows GUI subsystem program won't attach to the parent console even if one exists and a Linux GUI program may attach to the controlling tty of the X window manager.

---

What I'd actually recommend though is passing an argument to your function to tell it how it got started. When you create the GUI shortcut, make it automatically pass the "started by gui" argument to you. Then you can check `args` for it and react accordingly.

It still isn't perfect, but it is fairly easy to implement and probably good enough - gui launchers would probably use a shortcut anyway and you can pass arguments through them, so the user doesn't need to know about how it is implemented.

Or you could install two programs, one which is convenient from the command line and one which is optimized for the gui environment.

But I think that's the best you can do.